# @property of an object, tslint gives error - no-redundant-jsdoc

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jsdoc, tslint

I am using tslint for my typescript code.
I  want to document a property of an interface.
tsLint gives an error `JSDoc tag '@property' is redundant in TypeScript code. (no-redundant-jsdoc)tslint(1)`

The following is my comment

```
/**
 * @property value - number with a unit as string
 */
```

Disabling the tslint for next line also does not work.

[image: jsDoc @property and tslint disable does not work]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the fix for `no-redundant-jsdoc` issue in **tslint** that worked for me (basically I disabled lint from throwing that error/issue):

1. Open **tslint.json** file in your project root.
2. Replace the line `"no-redundant-jsdoc": true` with `"no-redundant-jsdoc": false`

Go back and check the errors/files in question. That should be fixed now.

Comment: Be careful: Although this disables the warning for this specific case, it also deactivates the rule for your whole project. In general, you don't want to do this for a specific false positive of your lint rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable this for the whole file if that if that would work for you?

Comment: Although it is not desirable for this case, I would still like to know how disabling lint in the whole file works.

Comment: @Kumar Sidharth: Although quite old, this should be done with `/* tslint:disable no-redundant-jsdoc*/` at the first line of your file. In general, this disables the rule for any subsequent lines until end of file. You can read more about this in [tslint's official docs on rule flags](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/rule-flags/).